# android studio - every R in class files has error

Tags: android, android-studio

In my project , every R has problem and there is a red line under it , there is no error in the project and I can work and run the application even build the apk file without any problem .

I tried to clear , rebuild , invalidate every thing and restart the android studio but the errors are still there

it's really bothering

how can I fix this ?

Comment: try to re-import or re-open the project

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko not working

Comment: Try “sync project with Gradle files”

Comment: @Brandon tried it but still not working

Comment: Open a new project, transfer /app to the new except /app/build. and transfer /build.gradle (project level) to that new

It happens when Android Studio gets angry :-D

Comment: One time I had the same problem. In my case, I just exit the app and open it again. Just restart didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of the following:

1) Try to perform a gradle clean by Build -> Clean Project.

2) Sync project with gradle files.

3) Check your xml files for invalid references.